# How to change dropdown content and an image when another dropdown box is changed?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have this javascript code, when dropdown A is changed, values of dropdown B and C are changed.

What I want to add is when dropdown A is changed it also changes the image too. `<img id="sheetimage" src="14_image.png"/>`

Actually the javascript was adapted from code only made to change 1 other drop down box so i wonder if it could be simplified also?

**HTML:**

```
<select id='pagetype' name='pagetype'>
<option value='14'>14 Per Sheet</option>
<option value='4'> 4 Per Sheet</option>
</select>

<select id='startlabel' name='startlabel'>
</select>

<select id='size' name='fontsize'>
</select>

<img id="sheetimage" src="14_image.png"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function(){
    //{"id":[{value:sweet, text:Sweet}.....]}
    var bOptions = {"14":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"], "4":["1","2","3","4"]};
var cOptions = {"14":["16","15","14","13"], "4":["36","32","28"]};

var A = document.getElementById('pagetype');
var B = document.getElementById('startlabel');
var C = document.getElementById('size');

A.onchange = function(){

    B.length = 0;
    C.length = 0;

    var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    for ( var i in bOptions[_val]){
        var op = document.createElement('option');
        op.value = bOptions[_val][i];
        op.text = bOptions[_val][i];
        B.appendChild(op);
    }

        for ( var i in cOptions[_val]){
        var op = document.createElement('option');
        op.value = cOptions[_val][i];
        op.text = cOptions[_val][i];
        C.appendChild(op);
    }

};

  A.onchange();

})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vn1gvrn6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working copy:

```js
(function() {
  //{"id":[{value:sweet, text:Sweet}.....]}
  var bOptions = {
    "14": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"],
    "4": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  };
  var cOptions = {
    "14": ["16", "15", "14", "13"],
    "4": ["36", "32", "28"]
  };
  var images = {
    "14": "img-14",
    "4": "img-4"
  };

  var A = document.getElementById('pagetype');
  var B = document.getElementById('startlabel');
  var C = document.getElementById('size');
  var D = document.getElementById('html');

  A.onchange = function() {

    B.length = 0;
    C.length = 0;

    var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {
      var op = document.createElement('option');
      op.value = bOptions[_val][i];
      op.text = bOptions[_val][i];
      B.appendChild(op);
    }

    for (var i in cOptions[_val]) {
      var op = document.createElement('option');
      op.value = cOptions[_val][i];
      op.text = cOptions[_val][i];
      C.appendChild(op);
    }

    D.className = images[_val];

  };

  A.onchange();

})();
```

```css
.img-14 {
  background-image: url('https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/apple_topic.png?w=220');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 50px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img-4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.technologytell.com/apple/files/2013/07/Apple_Logo_by_SA_08-258x300.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 50px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select id='pagetype' name='pagetype'>
  <option value='14'>14 Per Sheet</option>
  <option value='4'>4 Per Sheet</option>
</select>

<select id='startlabel' name='startlabel'>
</select>

<select id='size' name='fontsize'>
</select>

<img id="sheetimage" src="14_image.png" />

<textarea id='html' name='html'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great... Another question.. how could I change `D.setAttribute('src', images[_val]);` to cange the background image of this textarea `<textarea id='html' name='html'></textarea>` instead?

Comment: You can add a class for each value. See the update code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
img.src = "myImageUrl";
```